# Get related columns depending on a ID

Tags: mysql, mysqli

I have a table with a m:n (many to many) relationship. Basically, if I select an `article_id`, I want to return all the other articles that have the same `tag_id` as the selected `article_id`.

```
| article_id | tag_id |
|------------|--------|
| 1          | 2      |
| 1          | 11     |
| 2          | 5      |
| 4          | 6      |
| 4          | 11     |
| 12         | 9      |
| 14         | 9      |
| 14         | 15     |
| 14         | 17     |
| 18         | 1      |
| 20         | 8      |
| 41         | 13     |
| 49         | 9      |
| 50         | 12     |
| 60         | 18     |
| 75         | 9      |
| 75         | 10     |
| 75         | 11     |
```

So, if i select **article_id** 75 i need to output all of the articles that contains **tag_id** 9, 10 and 11

```
| article_id | tag_id |
|------------|--------|
| 1          | 11     |
| 4          | 11     |
| 12         | 9      |
| 14         | 9      |
| 49         | 9      |
```

I've created the following query and it looks like it works, but i want to make sure. Is there a better way?

```
SELECT aj2.article_id, aj2.tag_id
FROM article_tag_join aj
JOIN article_tag_join aj2 ON aj2.tag_id = aj.tag_id
WHERE aj.article_id = 75 AND aj2.article_id <> 75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the query slightly so that the exclusion is done within the join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT aj2.article_id, aj2.tag_id
  FROM article_tag_join AS aj
  JOIN article_tag_join AS aj2
    ON aj.tag_id = aj2.tag_id
   AND aj.article_id <> aj2.article_id
 WHERE aj.article_id = 75;
```

This *might* offer better performance, but it is always worth comparing it against your existing query. If I have two queries that result in the same execution plan, I pick the one that is easiest to maintain.